# How to write this URL rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Using [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29), is it possible to write rewrite rules to redirect URLs like the following?

```
http://example.com/topic/142 -> http://example.com/static/14/142.html
```

--Edit--

The rule is to get ID's first 2 numbers as folder name, then *`ID`*`.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^topic/(([0-9]{2})[0-9]*)$ static/$2/$1.html
```

Comment: @Martin Hohenberg: It will fail for numbers smaller than 10. And the folder name is identical to the ID for the numbers 10 to 99. But there is no upper limit.

Comment: hm, seems the OP was edited sometime after I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, yes, surely.

```
RewriteRule /topic/(.+) /static/14/$1.html
```

However, this will give you the `/14/` part every single time. As long as you don't have a hint were this part is encoded in your original URL, there is no way to change this.

Comment: rule added , seems impossible to archive this by rewrite

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(([0-9]{1,2})[0-9]*)$ /$2/$1.html
```

Greedy matching means that the first selector will pick up two characters if they are available.

However, I'm not sure that your rule makes much sense, as pages 14, 140-149 and 1400-1499 will be in the same directory.  Might it make more sense to put 0-99, 100-199, etc in the same directory?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,2})$ /0/$1.html
RewriteRule ^(([0-9]+)[0-9]{2})$ /$2/$1.html
```

Comment: my aim doing this is to avoid too many files within a folder , your rule makes sure there are no more then 100 files in a folder , it make more sense when there are so much files.